# Symfony lucene separate search fields

Tags: search, symfony1, lucene

I have table whit 4 field witch i want to search.
I indexing field like this:

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('pk', $this->getId()));
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('username', $this->getUsername(), 'utf-8'));
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('firstName', $this->getFirstName(), 'utf-8'));
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('lastName', $this->getLastName(), 'utf-8'));
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('city', $this->getCity(), 'utf-8'));
```

I want to separate search on this fields whith form Options.

```
<select name="contact[subject]" id="contact_subject">
  <option value="0">Username</option>
  <option value="1">First Name</option>
  <option value="2">Last Name</option>
  <option value="3">City</option>
</select>
```

How to tell Lucene to search result  only in field who i want ? 
I read many questions and explenations , but i dont get it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix your search term with the field's name:

```
$results = $li->find('username:"foobar"');
```

where `$li` is your lucene index.

Comment: If  I realized right, in My case thing need to look like this. $query='username:"user5"';
           $this->query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUser')->getAutocompleteQuery($query); What if i want to put * sumbol to search incomplete serach result ? I tried but dasn't have expwxted results .

Comment: Zend_Search_Lucene [supports wildcards](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html#zend.search.lucene.query-language.wildcard).

Comment: yes I alredy read this , but when i tried $results = $li->find('username:"foobar*"'); wildcard symbol dont work . I tried also $results = $li->find('username:"foobar"*'); and $results = $li->find('username:"foobar"'.'*');

Comment: Please elaborate on "dont work", this is not enough information to help.